# Saber si coincide el caracter y la pos de dos cadenas

Tags: python, string, funciones

Tengo el siguiente planteo: Hacer una función que reciba 2 códigos y retorne una lista con las
posiciones donde los caracteres de ambas cadenas coinciden.
Ejemplo:

```
código1 = “0161010-MET0-V11”
Código2 = “0181010-METE”
Retorno = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10]
```

Yo pensé pasar las dos cadenas a listas e ir viendo si i esta en la lista 2, hice el siguiente código.

```
def ambas(cadenaUno,cadenaDos):
    retorno=[]
    listaUno=list(cadenaUno)
    listaDos=list(cadenaDos)
    for i in range (len(listaDos)):
        if (listaDos[i] in listaUno):
            retorno.append(i)
    return retorno
```

Pero tengo el problema, que solo me revisa si coincide el carácter, y me lo agrega a la lista anqué sean repetidos y no quiero eso. Necesito que me controle que el carácter sea igual en la misma posición de ambas listas. Me pueden ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que usas

```
 if (listaDos[i] in listaUno):
```

lo que simplemente pregunta si el caracter de listaDos está en lista Uno, en lugar de

```
if listaDos[i] == listaUno[i]:
```

que es lo lógico, pues quieres comparar los caracteres posición por posición.

Lo segundo es que debes iterar sobre la cadena más corta, lo que puedes lograr aplicando `min` de los largos.

Con todo, queda así:

```
def ambas(cadenaUno,cadenaDos):
    retorno=[]
    listaUno=list(cadenaUno)
    listaDos=list(cadenaDos)
    largo = min(len(listaUno), len(listaDos))
    for i in range (largo):
        if listaUno[i] == listaDos[i]:
            retorno.append(i)
    return retorno
```

**Demo**

```
print('0123456789*123456789*')
print('0161010 - MET0 - V11')
print('0181010 - METE')
print(ambas('0161010 - MET0 - V11', '0181010 - METE'))
```

produce

```
0123456789*123456789*
0161010 - MET0 - V11
0181010 - METE
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Quise verificar los resultados imprimiendo ambas cadenas y una linea de marcadores.

Comment: Que es lo que realiza el "min", te devuelve la lista mas corta para empezar a comparar desde esa ? lo puedo remplazar por un if preguntando que lista es mas chica? disculpa la pregunta, recién estoy viendo python

Comment: `min(a,b)` te retorna el menor de los valores `a` y `b`. En este caso, `a` y `b` son los largos de las cadenas. Con eso obtengo el largo de la más corta. `min` es una función intrinsica, una de las más básica de Python, pero puedes usar un `if` si lo deseas.

Comment: lo probe y me tira error en  "for i in range (listaDos):" .. me dice "list" object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: ya lo arregle, muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 1):

Un efoque totalmente distinto, podría ser usar `zip` para unir cada caracter de las dos cadenas en tuplas, para luego comparar cada una de ellas y obtener la posición de aquellas tuplas coincidentes:

```
retorno = [i for i, tupla in enumerate(zip(codigo1, codigo2)) if tupla[0] == tupla[1]]

print(retorno)
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: También podrías desempaquetar la tupla creada con zip así: `[i for i, (tupla0, tupla1) in enumerate(zip(codigo1, codigo2)) if tupla0 == tupla1]`